# vectorized function fminsearch

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization

Thank you very much,first. The first code runs well:
    function f=malibu(m1,m2,m3,k,l,t)
    f=(m1.*k+(m1+m2).*l).*exp(-m3.*t);
    end

```
function loglik= modelmalibu(p)
global k l t x n m2 m3;
f =malibu(p,m2,m3,k,l,t);
if f==0;
    loglik0=0;
else
loglik0=(x.*log(f)+(n-x).*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
end
loglik=sum(-loglik0);
end

clear all;
global n t x k l m2 m3;
m1=0.1;
m2=0.2;
m3=0.3;
t=[1 3 6 9 12 18]';
k=[1 1 2 3 3 4]';
l=[0 0 1 3 4 5]';
y=meltem(m1,m2,m3,k,l,t);
n=100;%trial
x=y.*n;%correct replies
pstart=0.3;
[p1,modelvalue]=fminsearch(@modelmalibu,pstart);
```

But the similar code for more variable gives error out.

```
function w=anemon(m1,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l)
w=(m1.*k+(m1+m2).*l)+X.*exp(-m3.*Y);
end

function loglik= modelanemon(p)
global n x m2 m3 X Y k l ;
f =anemon(p,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l);
if f==0;
    loglik0=0;
else
loglik0=(x*log(f)+(n-x)*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
end
loglik=sum(-loglik0);
end

clear;
global n x Ydata kdata ldata m1 m2 m3;
%parameters
m1=0.002;
m2=0.0001;
m3=7;
%given data
Xdata=[1 3 6 9 10 12]';
Ydata=[11 13 41 81 121 181]';
kdata=[1 1 2 4 5 4]';
ldata=[1 1 3 3 4 5]';
y=anemon(m1,m2,m3,Xdata,Ydata,kdata,ldata);
n=10;
x=y.*n;
pstart=2;
[pbest,modelvalue]=fminsearch(@modelanemon,pstart);
```

I've actually tried to use your advises, but if I would write an inequality instead of f==0, the first code fall down as well.

Comment: It looks like all your "Mfile"s consist of comments only. Do you have really "%" in front of every line in those files. If this is the case, then your code is not doing much. Otherwise, please edit your post.

Comment: @Kavka, thank you for your comment. I only want to underline the part of M-Files but I see after your comment how confusing the idea was. I edited it as you advised.

Comment: I have a problem understanding what your question is. Can you clarify? - maybe on a small snippet, or a specific example.

Comment: @bdecaf, thanks for your interest. When I define my model for a basic function like my "anemon" and want to use it in fminsearch, it runs. Then I thougt what happens if I have much complicated cases. Every single Mfile function I wrote,separately runs well.For example:interpanemon(3,5,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,4,3). But fminsearch dosen't like comlicated functions. First I thougt, that I should vektorize my function,but it didn't work too.Probably, in this case fminsearce assume that the parameter is constant. Actually, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two concepts.

*vectorization:* does refer in how to write your code so it can use some of the acceleration functions in your CPU. it has nothing to do with fminsearch. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(parallel_computing)

I suppose you want to write your function such that it accepts a vector as input. Easiest way is to just use a function handle like this:

```
fh = @(x) my_complicated_function(const1, const2, x(1), x(2), x(3) )
```

In this case my_complicated_function has 5 inputs, and you take the first 2 constant and input a 3 dim vector for the other 3. Fminsearch will work with that.

You would call

```
 x_opt = fminsearch(fh, [1,2,3])
```

---

Besides some tips for the code:

- Don't use `==` for comparison of numbers - go for eg. `abs(x1-x2)<0.1` instead
- `interpanemon` looks very strange - it doesn't do what one would call interpolation, and if you look - in every iteration p is recalculated so only the last calculation takes effect. As it looks it should output a constant value - no use optimizing that.
- The use of a precalculated Z is probably not what you want. It already determines your optimum. If you use linear optimization the optimum must be already in Z - no need doing interpolation.
- The invocation in your case might look like:

  min_p = fminsearch(@(x) interpanemon(5,Ydata,x,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kdata,ldata) ,1)

Overall it looks very unusual - it could really help if you would explain the ideas WHY you choose to do it like this. Also it might help if you restate the problem in a simpler form.

Comment: ,thank you very much for your help.Appearently,I'm an idiot but I still didn't understand well.If I dont bother you,could you please explain that: At the beginning I assume taht I do not have any data. I create the function anemon(m1,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l), that by aid of this function I create a function Z(i,j,k,l) on the grid (X(i),Y(j)).Then I determine the function for the points Xstar, Ystar)between grid pointsandwrite interpanemon(Xstar,Ystar,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,k,l ).Than I get some dataand want to minimize interpanemon(5,Ydata,p,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kdata,ldata) fminsearch should do it for p,but :(.

Comment: hmmm... at first I see some problems with your code. I add some tips.

Comment: variable number. I get trouble:(`function w=anemon(m1,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l)
w=(m1.*k+(m1+m2).*l)+X.*exp(-m3.*Y);
end` and model `function loglik= modelanemon(p)
global n x m2 m3 X Y k l ;
f =anemon(p,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l);
if f==0;
    loglik0=0;
else
loglik0=(x*log(f)+(n-x)*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
end
loglik=sum(-loglik0);
end` doesn't run with the same script below

Comment: `%script anemon
clear;
global n x Ydata kdata ldata m1 m2 m3;
%parameters
m1=0.002;
m2=0.0001;
m3=7;
%given data
Xdata=[1 3 6 9 10 12]';
Ydata=[11 13 41 81 121 181]';
kdata=[1 1 2 4 5 4]';
ldata=[1 1 3 3 4 5]';
y=anemon(m1,m2,m3,Xdata,Ydata,kdata,ldata);
n=10;
x=y.*n;
pstart=2;
[pbest,modelvalue]=fminsearch(@modelanemon,2)`

Comment: runs well`function f=malibu(m1,m2,m3,k,l,t)
f=(m1.*k+(m1+m2).*l).*exp(-m3.*t);
end` and model `function loglik= modelmalibu(p)
global k l t x n m2 m3;
f =malibu(p,m2,m3,k,l,t);
if f==0;
    loglik0=0;
else
%f=(f<ones(41,1)).*f+(f>ones(41,1))*1;%0<f<1
loglik0=(x.*log(f)+(n-x).*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
end
loglik=sum(-loglik0);
end` with script`clear all;
global n t x k l m2 m3;
m1=0.1;
m2=0.2;
m3=0.3;
t=[1 3 6 9 12 18]';
k=[1 1 2 3 3 4]';
l=[0 0 1 3 4 5]';
y=meltem(m1,m2,m3,k,l,t);
n=100;%trial
x=y.*n;%correct replies
pstart=0.3;
[p1,modelvalue]=fminsearch(@modelmalibu,pstart);`

Comment: I'm sorry - through the formatting in comments your code became unreadable. Could you add it to your question?